# How to use c5.0control parameters

Tags: r, classification, decision-tree

Hi i am new in using R and i am building decision trees using c5.0 algorithm. For better accuracy i need to use boosting and c5.0control function different parameters. i have understand the concept of boosting by ?trials and learned how actually it helps. but for parameters of c5.0control like "Subset" , "noGlobalPruning" , "minCases" , "sample" i cant understand by reading the default definitions in R studio it self.

So can any one help me in giving description of these parameters specified other than the original R description provided?

Comment: Is it the R implementation in particular that you are unsure of? What model exactly are you trying to create. If you have questions about the underlying statistical model, you'd probably be better off asking at [stats.se] instead since statistical questions are on topic there.

Comment: @MrFlick thans for the reply. Its nor r implementation actually i want to know about the parameters that what they actually mean and how they can help me in building decision trees with better accuracy and less error%. iam using c5.0 algorithm for building trees and i want to use c5.0control function of this algorithm to help me with parameters mentioned in question

Comment: Then that's not a programing question so it's not appropriate for Stack Overflow as previously indicated.

Comment: I like to use the winnowing parameter set to TRUE which removes unhelpful attributes. I also like to use tree-based models rather than rule-based so I set rules = FALSE. In certain cases, you can also implement a cost matrix to weight misclassification types. For example, a false negative might be deemed to be more costly than a false positive.